# How to get multiple parameters from url in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a URL that look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/refer?my_id=some_id&my_name=abc
```

I want to get the value of `my_id` and `my_name` in the URL.

**This is what I tried:**

Therefore in my `pages/refer.js` I do like this:

```
export default class Referral extends React.Component{

  static getInitialProps({query:{my_id,my_name}}) {
    return {my_id,my_name}
  }

  render() {
        return (
           <h1>My id = {this.props.my_id}</h1>
           <h1>My name =  {this.props.my_name}</h1>

        )
   }
};
```

But the result is I only get the value of `my_id` ,but cant get the value of `my_name`. I looked at this page - [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), but seems like not possible to get the second value after the "&" sign.

Comment: what Next version do you have?

Comment: Could you try like ```this.props.router.query.my_id``` and ```this.props.router.query.my_name``` ?

Comment: @zynkn  next js version v9.4.4

Comment: @ManirajMurugan i tried but I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` for the `this.props.router.query.my_id`

Comment: @ken I had a test with the same code, but it looks well.

Comment: @zynkn lol..now work ady..I dont know what I done right..but it just work now

Comment: thanks guys..Now it work with the same code.

Comment: @ken it works? good.

Comment: @zynkn It works..but I dont know what I done right

Comment: @ken sometimes it happened with no reason.